Does rigid foam on the exterior wall of an off-grid cabin need a vapor barrier?
( I found a question stream that seemed relevant but then when I logged in, can't find it, thus my own question).
I just bought an off-grid cabin. Much of the interior is open stud walls and open joists. It has a nice look but I want to add some insulation where I can. I've started insulating under the floor. There's a long cabinet against the stud wall in one corner. The exterior is plywood with cedar siding. Can I put rigid foam in the stud spaces behind the cabinet without adding a vapor barrier? I'm assuming I'd use spray foam for a complete seal. Thanks, folks. The cabin is at ~3,600' in central B.C., Canada.

That would depend on the permeability (or lack theof) of the particular "rigid foam" which you have not identified. they are not all the same, chemically or physical properties-wise

Incidentally, if you need a vapor barrier, it would go on the side of the insulation facing the interior, not the exterior.  You want to protect the insulation from the warm, humid interior, not the cold, dry exterior.  That reverses in climates where you insulate to keep the interior cool.  You always want the vapor barrier on the warmer side.

I'm wide open to recommendations on rigid foam. I used TerraFoam (an EPS foam) to insulate the floor joists but it's messy to work with (much debris from cutting). The rigid foam I have is 10-15 years old and only on my list because it's handy and paid for. However, I need to do this right as I only want to do it once so any info you can offer will be well-received. :) Thanks.
